# Adding items from one listbox to another with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, listbox, tkinter

As the title implies I'm trying to select items from one list box, press a button, and add it to a second list box.

When I click the button to move, the value is printed in command prompt, but the listbox itself isn't updating.

I copied and pasted so I realize that everything should be tabbed over one spot.

```
class Actions: 

def openfile(self): #select a directory to view files
    directory = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(initialdir='.')
    self.directoryContents(directory)


def filename(self):
    Label (text='Please select a directory').pack(side=TOP,padx=10,pady=10)

files = []
fileListSorted = []

#display the contents of the directory
def directoryContents(self, directory): #displays two listBoxes containing items
    scrollbar = Scrollbar() #left scrollbar - display contents in directory
    scrollbar.pack(side = LEFT, fill = Y) 

    scrollbarSorted = Scrollbar() #right scrollbar - display sorted files 
    scrollbarSorted.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y, padx = 2, pady=100)

    fileList = Listbox(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set) #files displayed in the left listBox
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        fileList.insert(END, filename)
        global files 
        self.files.append(filename) #insert the values into the files array so we know which element we want to enter in moveFile
    fileList.pack(side =LEFT, fill = BOTH)
    scrollbar.config(command = fileList.yview)


    global fileListSorted #this is for the filelist in the right window. contains the values the user has selected
    fileListSorted = Listbox(yscrollcommand = scrollbarSorted.set) #second listbox (button will send selected files to this window)
    fileListSorted.pack(side=RIGHT, fill = BOTH)
    scrollbarSorted.config(command = fileListSorted.yview)

    selection = fileList.curselection() #select the file
    b = Button(text="->", command=lambda:self.moveFile(fileList.curselection()))#send the file to moveFile to be added to fileListSorted
    b.pack(pady=5, padx =20)


##moveFile addes files to the array fileLIst2, which is the fileList on the right
def moveFile(self,File):
    insertValue = int(File[0]) #convert the item to integer
    global files
    insertName = self.files[insertValue] #get the name of the file to be inserted

    global fileListSorted
    self.fileListSorted.append(str(insertName)) #append the value to the fileList array
    print self.fileListSorted #second listbox list
```

Comment: is this code nested into a class? There is a strange mix between global variables and members methods. i think you should refactor: remove globals and put everything into a class

Comment: Yes, it's in a class. I'll re-post with the entire class

Comment: If you realize the code needs to be tabbed over, why don't you do that? Take pride in the quality of the questions you ask.

Comment: Bryan, my choice was to either leave "Class Actions" on the same column as my functions, or tab 50 lines of code. I don't think it made my question misleading (my crappy code to begin with did though!). Is there some sort of copy with formatting for stack overflow? I figured there would be considering python isn't exactly a tiny language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite difficult to follow that code -- For example, where is `self.fileListSorted` defined? -- You have a global `fileListSorted` and an instance variable `self.fileListSorted` and they're different things.  However, you seem to be getting them confused (for example, why is there a line

```
global fileListSorted
```

in `moveFile` when you never use `fileListSorted` in there?)  Also note that to add items into a `ListBox`, you typically use the `insert` method, which you haven't used in `moveFiles` as far as you've shown anyway...

Comment: I tried using insert(END, ...) but I got an error saying there must be an integer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a beginner, especially when it comes to OOP with python. I changed self.fileListSorted to just fileLIst and it works.

Comment: @user1104854 -- No problem.  Just glad to help. :).  keep learning python -- It's a pretty powerful language.